# Grub lists unknown kernels

Tags: grub2

When I boot (Ubuntu 14.04) Grub does not load the OS. If I list Advanced Options, grub lists kernels up to `3.13.0-100-generic`, however `uname -r` outputs `3.13.0-96-generic`.

I have installed grub Customizer, and it also only sees

```
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic        
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic        
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic        
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-96-generic
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I haven't used grub Customizer but in this instance it might be wrong. Use `ls /boot/vm*` to see all the linux kernels available.

Answer (score 2):

For a definitive answer of what's installed run this:

```
ls /boot/vm*
```

If grub menu doesn't agree with the list then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

When you run:

```
uname -r
```

It lists the kernel you booted with which isn't always the newest one you might see in advanced options menu.